# Proving by Contrapositive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am given this statement ... *Use a proof by contrapositive to show that if n is an integer and n^2 is odd, then n
must be odd.*

Since its prove by contrapositive I have to to assume the negation. which is Assuming n is an even integer and that n^2 is even as well. By definition n could be represented as 2k (2 for  some k). To proof the statement do i just plug in 2k and square it to show that by definition it is even and not odd?

Comment: Yes, precisely, noting in particular that $(2k)^2 = 2(2k^2)$ and that $2k^2$ is an integer.

Comment: Yep.  if $n = 2k$ then $(2k)^2 = ????= 2*M$ and is that even or odd.  If it is even then $n$ even $\implies n^2$ is even.  And therefore $n^2$ odd and $n$ even is impossible.  SO $n^2$ odd $\implies n$ odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep.  This is a relatively easy one and you figured it out.

> $n^2$ is odd $\implies n$ is odd

is equivalent to

> $n$ is even $\implies n^2$ is even.

And we prove that:

If $n$ is even then there is an integer $k$ so that $n = 2k$.

Then $(2k)^2 = 4k^2 = 2(2k^2)$.  And as $2k^2$ is an integer $2(2k^2)=n^2$ is even.

That's it.  We're done.

Answer (score 5):

The contrapositive to a statement "$P$ implies $Q$" is "not $Q$ implies not $P$". Symbolically,

$$(P \implies Q) \iff (\neg Q \implies \neg P)$$

That is, you not only assume the negation but you effectively swap around what implies what.

Thus, if you are trying to prove "if $n$ is an integer with $n^2$ odd, then $n$ is odd", then the contrapositive is "if $n$ is an even integer, then $n^2$ is even." This is basically what you said, but notice how it is a little more nuanced than simply negating the statement. (Above, $P$ can be taken as "$n^2$ is odd" and $Q$ as "$n$ is odd.")

To prove this statement, you can thus indeed say $n=2k$ for some integer $k$, and then show $2$ divides $n^2$, making it even. This follows quite easily, as...

> $$n^2 = (2k)^2 = 4k^2 = 2(2k^2)$$

Comment: The contrapositive is not "a little more nuanced than negating the statement", it is something completely different. The contrapositive is equivalent to the forward direction, which means the negated statement is its exact opposite.

Answer (score 2):

For contrapositive proof you have to assume that $n$ is even and prove that $n^2$ is even.

In general $P\implies Q$ is equivalent to  $\lnot Q\implies\lnot P$

and that is why you need to switch them around and make negations.

Comment: Ok i get it now! Its important to switch them around first. Thank you!